# Terraform reports a change to Application Insights key on every plan that is run

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have several Azure resources that are created using the for_each property and then those resources have an Application Insights resource created using for_each as well.

Here is the code that creates the azurerm_application_insights:

```
resource "azurerm_application_insights" "applicationInsights" {
  for_each            = toset(keys(merge(local.appServices, local.functionApps)))
  name                = lower(join("-", ["wb", var.deploymentEnvironment, var.location, each.key, "ai"]))
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  application_type    = "web"
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [tags]
  }
}
```

I've noticed that every time we run a terraform plan against some environments, we are always seeing Terraform report a "change" to the APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY value. When I compare this value in the app settings key/value list to the actual AI instrumentation key that was created for it, it *does match*.

```
 Terraform will perform the following actions:
 
   # module.primaryRegion.module.functionapp["fnapp1"].azurerm_function_app.fnapp will be updated in-place
   ~ resource "azurerm_function_app" "fnapp" {
       ~ app_settings                   = {
           # Warning: this attribute value will be marked as sensitive and will
           # not display in UI output after applying this change
           ~ "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" = (sensitive) 
             # (1 unchanged element hidden)
```

Is this a common issue with other people? I would think that the instrumentation key would never change especially since Terraform is what created all of these Application Insights resources and assigns it to each application.

This is how I associate each Application Insights resource to their appropriate application with a for_each property

```
module "webapp" {
  for_each              = local.appServices
  source                = "../webapp"
  name                  = lower(join("-", ["wb", var.deploymentEnvironment, var.location, each.key, "app"]))
  location              = var.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  app_service_plan_id   = each.value.app_service_plan_id
  app_settings          = merge({"APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" = azurerm_application_insights.applicationInsights[each.key].instrumentation_key}, each.value.app_settings)
  allowed_origins       = each.value.allowed_origins
  deploymentEnvironment = var.deploymentEnvironment
}
```

I'm wondering if the merge is just reordering the list of key/values in the app_settings for the app, and Terraform detects that as some kind of change and the value itself isn't changing. This is the only way I know how to assign a bunch of Application Insights resources to many web apps using for_each to reduce configuration code.

Comment: Could you also add TF code for resource "azurerm_function_app" "fnapp" to your question?

Comment: This isn't specific to function app, though.

Comment: I have seen something similar happen with other Azure resources, mostly Application Gateways, Azure Firewall, Azure NSGs. E.g. When changing adding/modifying one rule to any of those resources, a TF plan will show destroy/create for non-resources. When proceeding with an apply, nothing actually changes. I've also come to the conclusion that it probably just reorganises the different items within the resource, although in the case of NSGs I realised what was happening was just new (product update related) attributes to the resource by Azure, that were missing in the initial TF code.

Comment: I can see there's issue that has been raised already, which could be related to yours - no updates yet though. https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/5972

Answer (score 0):

Use only the **Site_config** block  to solve the issue
Example

```
resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "function2" {
  provider = azurerm.private
  name                = local.private.functionapps.function2.name
  resource_group_name = local.private.rg.app.name
  location            = local.private.location

  storage_account_name       = local.private.functionapps.storageaccount.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.function_apps_storage.primary_access_key
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.app_service_plan.id
  virtual_network_subnet_id = lookup(azurerm_subnet.subnets, "appservice").id
  https_only = true

  site_config  {
    application_insights_key = azurerm_application_insights.appinisghts.instrumentation_key
  }
}
```